# How to keep an element at the bottom of the page updating the height of the element above it to occupy all the space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, chat

Hi I need to create a layout for a chat window, basically like the one on the Facebook Messages page: The chat input textarea box is aways at the bottom of the window and the scroll content of the messages occupies all the free space, look at this images:

without zoom out:

[image]

Then when zooming out:

[image]

The chat input textarea is always at the bottom, and the height of the scroll div which contains the messages changes, even if I press F12 and the console appears:
[image]

Now my situation is almost the same, and this is what I did:
I have this layout:
[image]

The #top-bar contains the header of the page, the chat head is the header of the chatbox, the messages-chat-container is the div that contains the scroll with all the messages and the #new-message-chat-container contains the textarea input. I need it to be always at the bottom, so I wrote this JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
            adjustHeight();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
            adjustHeight();
    }, 500); 
 });

 function adjustHeight() {
    var header = $("$top-bar");

    var headerHeight = getJQElementHeight(header);
    $(".content").height($(window).height() - headerHeight);

    $("#messages-chat-container").height(getJQElementHeight($(".content")) - getJQElementHeight($("#new-message-chat-container")) );

}

  function getJQElementHeight (selector) {
    return selector.outerHeight(true);
  }
```

the .content class is of a  that wraps the #chat-head, the #messages-chat-container and the #new-message-chat-container.

But it doesn't work, or better, it does but the #new-message-chat-container is cut meaning that it is not all showed but only a part and to see it all I must scroll down. I would like to see it all and at the bottom instead.

What am I missing? Is there a guide or something that explains well this technique?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, but it may require CSS3 if you're OK with that:

```
div#top, div#new-message
{
    position: fixed; // or absolute (it depends)
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; // this is the css3 bit
    // you need this if you have extra padding and borders and margins
}

div#top
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
}

div#new-message
{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 120px;
}

div#chat-messages
{
    padding-top: 80px; // height of the bar on the top
    padding-bottom: 120px; // height of the bar on the bottom
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chat-messages"></div>

<div id="top"></div> <!-- These two are to be above the chat -->
<div id="new-message"></div> <!-- You might want to set a z-index -->
```

Here's a link to an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8wB/

Here's what `box-sizing: border-box` means according to w3schools.com:

> The specified width and height (and min/max properties) on this element determine the border box of the element. That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified 'width' and 'height' properties

Comment: I added a fiddle as an example.

Comment: I like the idea of using the position:absolute or fixed and then pushing the #new-messages div at the bottom adding a padding to the #messages-chat-container div. You are saying that this requires CSS3, what can I do in order to make it compatible with old browsers? like IE7 or less?

Comment: ADDED: I looked at the fiddle and if you note when you zoom-in the page, the bottom div#bottom overlays the #top div and the #messages div, how can I make it (#bottom message) to block at a certain zoom in in order to keep at least two messages in the #chat div displayed and dispay the topbar?

Comment: @user3019105 For the element that contains the topbar and the bottombar (in the fiddle's case `body`), you can set a `min-height: 350px` or whatever, so that zooming in won't cover all of the chat up.

Comment: I have tried what you say in the fiddle, added min-height: 350px to the body but it didn't work, maybe there's another way?

Comment: @user3019105 Yeah, `min-height` is kinda buggy. I tried it as well and now I don't think you can make that work unless you specify the heights of the bars in percentages, but I don't know if you want to do that.

Comment: I didn't understand how you can handle it with percentages, could you post an update of the fiddle with an example please?

Comment: @user3019105 Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8wB/3/ But, like I said, you might not want to do this. Because the heights of the bars change.

Comment: @user3019105 Yeah, you really dont want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to put the two "bars" in their own seperate `div` floating above the chat.

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/SWLwA/1/

(The JQuery is just to fill up the chat.)